# Issue with primeflex styles in conjunction with tailwind responsive

Tags: css, tailwind-css, primereact, tailwind-ui, primeflex

I'm facing an issue with primeFlex styles when used in conjunction with Tailwind. Due to the importance given to Tailwind styles, the responsive styles are not functioning as expected. The problem is illustrated in this image:

[image: problem]

As evident from the image, default styles have the !important flag, and even if I apply the !important flag to the responsive styles, the text color remains unchanged.

The code:
`<div className='mt-5 text-[#FFFFFF99] text-[11px] md:text-red-500 text-green-500'>`

How to fix this issue and make default styles work less than md size (text green when width less than md), but after md - text must be red. With this issue text in every size is green cause important flag

Comment: Have you following this TailWind demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/gkxmmw?file=src%2FApp.jsx   can you reproduce the issue on StackBlitz?